# flask: command not found - flask 0.12

Tags: python, flask

I have just installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and installed flask using `pip3 install flask`. When I run `pip3 list` Flask 0.12 appears in the list.

However, when I attempt to run `flask`, I get the error `flask: command not found`.

I have also installed using `pip` and not `pip3` but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed by running `python3 -m flask`.

Answer (score -1):

Windows:

```
pip install flask
```

MacOS:

```
sudo pip install flask
```

Raspberry Pi:

```
sudo apt-get install flask
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install flask` doesn't work for me; I get `E: Unable to locate package flask`